# Do not fire an event when the variable value is empty

Tags: regex, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to create a trigger in gtm that will not fire a tag when click url variable is empty. Is that possible? Or the other way round if it contains something

Click url, does not contain, undefined - that doesn't work

To be more precise, I've added a tag that tracks outbound links, but excluding my own domain isn't enough, because it also sends events when someone clicks a link that doesn't contain a target url like adding a job offer to shortlist.

Comment: It probably doens't work becuase click url is not undefined but empty

Answer (score 6):

You can create a trigger that only fires when a variable has a value by checking that the value does not match RegEx `^$`. The RegEx `^$` will check for an empty string value, which is not what we want.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can set up a trigger that will fire if Click Url length is more than 1 with regex /.+/ and use this trigger to fire your tracking tag

Comment: 'length' is not available.

Comment: you can use regex to check if a string is more than X of length, right?

Comment: I believe you can use regex to check if a string contains certain value(s).